# Getting text missed when & symbol is in a parameter of a js function called by python

Tags: javascript, python, naked-objects

I have been using the Naked.toolshed.shell library of python to launch a js script with a gived argument.
The problemm is that when "&" is in the argument js only obtains what goes before that symbol, for example
Python:

```
from Naked.toolshed.shell import execute_js, muterun_js
link ="example_of_a_link.com/width=640&crop....."
response = execute_js('/file.js', link)
```

Js:

```
var pi = process.argv[2];
console.log(pi);
```

And what CMD shows:

```
example_of_a_link.com/width=640
```

So & and what goes after is missed, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escape the `&` with `^` by passing...

```
link.replace('&', '^&')
```

...to `execute_js()`